# Excel vba parse formula

Tags: parsing, excel, vba

I have some excel sheets with calculated fields, e.g. CELL_C =FIELD_A+FIELD_B. I need to extract all cells from that formula for highlight it with different color.
Is there any built-in VBA function to parse cell.Formula to get the range of cells?

Comment: Your explanation is too scarce. Please provide a screenshot or elaborate more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always get the first-level precedents with something like:

```
Sub qwerty()
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = ActiveCell.Precedents
  If rng Is Nothing Then
  Else
    MsgBox rng.Address(0, 0)
  End If
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Gary - I didn't know about `.Precedents` - looks very useful!

Comment: @FreeMan  There are some restrictions associated with .Precedents.

Comment: need to use NavigateArrows to find off sheet precedents